# How do you encapsulate logic/html using MVC/Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

So I really like the MVC concept, but I'm having a hard time seeing how to properly encapsulate content. Regular ASP.net had the concept of controls, but that seems to run contrary to the MVC thought process, so how do you properly compartmentalize/encapsulate content in MVC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MVC has many ways to reuse code.

- Html Helpers
- Partial Views
- Editor Templates
- Razor Helpers
- Layouts

All of these are used in different situations, for different reasons.  You should read up on them to understand what they are.

Comment: +1.  And the day they add razor view support in a shared library "DLL" fashion will be my shangrila :)

Comment: @Moo-Juice - Not sure what you mean, as there are a number of ways to put views in a DLL.

Comment: @MystereMan Man Please share.

Comment: @sircodesalot - Views can be added as resources or they can be compiled into the DLL as just two examples.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's pretty straightforward isn't it. Shangrila!

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to componentize UI parts:

- Layout page (this is similar to a MasterPage in WebForms)
- PartialViews (Similar to UserControls in WebForms)
- Editor- and DisplayTemplates (show a UI for a specific Type)
- Html helpers: create a specific control based on code

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to view composition then MVC supports a number of different techniques including partial views, child actions, html helpers, templated html helpers and inline templates.